# regex works, but in html form will not allow anything

Tags: html, regex, forms

I created this bit go regex in the regexer website and it worked with the things I entered, I want to to allow upper and lowercase letters but to not allow combinations over 40 characters, this is the regex...

```
^[a-z]|[A-Z]{1,40}$
```

the line of code is...

```
First name:<input type="text" name="firstname" pattern= ^[a-z]|[A-Z]{1,40}$>
```

Comment: You forgot your quotes around your regex

Comment: HTML attributes need quotes around their values, either double or single. Also the space that you left in should better be removed. And I was going to add that the pattern is incorrect, but there are answers already covering that.

Comment: I have tried that, but it hasn't made a difference

Comment: `First name:<input type="text" name="firstname" pattern='^[a-z]|[A-Z]{1,40}$'> ` this still will not accept anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paroblem with `^[a-z]|[A-Z]{1,40}$` is that the pattern will get parsed as `/^(?:^[a-z]|[A-Z]{1,40}$)$/` and thus will match a string that only equals a lowercase ASCII letter or 1 to 40 uppercase ASCII letters (without allowing lowercase ones).

You should fix the pattern like this:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,40}">
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will only let users input 1 to 40 ASCII letters.

This regex will be parsed as `/^(?:[a-zA-Z]{1,40})$/` by the HTML5 engine where `^` matches the start of input and `$` matches the end of input.

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text" name="firstname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,40}" title="Please type 1 to 40 ASCII letters only.">
  <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Another way to control the length with a pattern is to use `required maxlength="40"` and then you may use a `[A-Za-z]+` pattern:

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input type="text" name="firstname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" required maxlength="40" title="Please type 1 to 40 ASCII letters only.">
  <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:
[`^[a-zA-Z]{1,40}$`](https://regex101.com/r/dmMh2K/1)

For the [pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) attribute you could also use `[a-zA-Z]{1,40}`.

```html
<input type="text" name="firstname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{1,40}">
```